# chi square test power analysis without effect size

Tags: r

I need to find sample size needed to perform chi square test. The information I have are alpha(0.05) and power (0.8). I don't have effect size. How do I find the sample size needed.

Comment: It will be effect size dependent won't it?

Answer (score 1):

First, load the pwr library. If you want to find N, you have to estimate the effect size w, and know the df which will be (row-1)*(col-1) from your contingency table. So for a proportion of 0.3 in the first group and proportion of 0.5 in the second group (the ES function will give you effect size from these), a 2x2 contingency table (df=(2-1)*(2-1)), a desired significance level of 0.95 and desired power of 0.8:

```
> library(pwr)
> pwr.chisq.test(w=ES.w1(0.3,0.5),df=1,sig.level=0.05,power=0.80)

   Chi squared power calculation 

      w = 0.3651484
      N = 58.86645
      df = 1
      sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.8

NOTE: N is the number of observations
```

If you put your numbers in and get an error like this:

```
Error in uniroot(function(N) eval(p.body) - power, c(1 + 0.0000000001,  : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

...there are several answers elsewhere on here that can help you through that; see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Error+in+uniroot